# How to display parameters on PlotLegends?

Tags: plotting, legending

I used the following code to generate a plot for a function with four different parameters.

```
Plot[
 Evaluate@Table[(100*(1 - (x - 1)^(-1/r))/((x - 1)^(1 - 1/r) + 1)),
   {r, 0.2, 0.8, 0.2}],
 {x, 2, 6},
 AxesLabel -> {"X", "y (Ooptimal choice)"}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

The results are as follows:

[image]

I want `PlotLegends` to show parameters; i.e., `"r = 0.2", "r = 0.4"` etc. rather than the expressions. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[(100*(1 - (x - 1)^(-1/r))/((x - 1)^(1 - 1/r) + 1))
   , {r, 0.2, 0.8, 0.2}]
 , {x, 2, 6}
 , AxesLabel -> {"X", "y (Ooptimal choice)"}
 , PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[Automatic
    , StringForm["r=``", #] & /@ Range[0.2, 0.8, 0.2]]
   , After
   ]
 ]
```

---

Another variation:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
params = Range[0.2, 0.8, 0.2]
exprs = Evaluate@
  Table[(100*(1 - (x - 1)^(-1/r))/((x - 1)^(1 - 1/r) + 1))
   , {r, params}]
labels = StringForm["r = ``", NumberForm[#, 2]] & /@ params
Plot[Evaluate@MapThread[
   Callout[Tooltip@#1, #2] &, {exprs, labels}]
 , {x, 2, 6}
 , AxesLabel -> {"X", "y (Optimal choice)"}
 (*,PlotLegends\[Rule]Placed[LineLegend[Automatic,labels]
 ,After]*)
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
Module[
    {
        params =Table[r,  {r, 0.2, 0.8, 0.2}]
    },
    Plot[
        Evaluate[
            ReplaceAll[
                (100*(1 - (x - 1)^(-1/r))/((x - 1)^(1 - 1/r) + 1))
                , r -> params
            ]
        ]
        , {x, 2, 6}
        , FrameLabel   -> {"X", "y (Ooptimal choice)"}
        , PlotTheme   -> "Detailed"
        , PlotLegends -> StringTemplate["r = ``"] /@ params
    ]
]
```

[image]

or

```
Module[
    {
        params = Table[r,  {r, 0.2, 0.8, 0.2}],
        expre  = (100*(1 - (x - 1)^(-1/r))/((x - 1)^(1 - 1/r) + 1))
    },
    Plot[
        Evaluate[
            ReplaceAll[
                expre
                , r -> params
            ]
        ]
        , {x, 2, 6}
        , FrameLabel   -> {"X", "Y (Optimal choice)"}
        , PlotTheme   -> "Scientific"
        , PlotLegends -> StringTemplate["r = ``"] /@ params
        , Epilog-> Inset[Framed[TraditionalForm[Factor@expre]], {5,20}]
    ]
]
```

[image]